# order using the English possessive

Tags: word-order, possessives

I think it is a pretty simple question. I am not sure which sentence sounds better:

> Please send me the last two file's pages.

> Please send me the file's last two pages

Would a sentence without using the possessive be preferable in this case?

> The last two pages of the file.

PS: I think everyone can understand what I want to say but if that is not the case, please let me know and I will try to add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The file's last two pages* is how you'd phrase it - the noun phrase that's possessed by *the file* is *last two pages*. If you split that phrase up, into *last two* and *pages*, it sounds strange.

And by saying *the last two file's pages*, it sounds more like you're talking about the *pages* belonging to *the last two files*, that *last two* determiner has attached itself to *file's* instead. The apostrophe doesn't fit (it should be *files'*) so that's a clue that something's wrong, but you can't hear apostrophes, and if you said that out loud it would sound like *the last two files' pages", i.e. (all) the pages from the last two files.

*The last two pages of the file* is perfectly fine, you've just moved the entire *last two pages* noun phrase to another position, but kept it intact. Either that or *the file's last two pages* is completely fine and clear!